# Is it possible to open a raw disk in PHP on Windows?

Tags: php, windows, php-8

I am trying to open the raw disk on Windows/PHP. (Like `/dev/sda` on Linux.)

I tried (as admin):

```
fopen("\\\\?\\Device\\Harddisk1\\Partition0");
```

I have this path from [here](https://superuser.com/questions/1204522/dev-sda-equivalent-in-windows). Yes, it's the whole disk and not a partition.

But I get:

```
 fopen(\\?\Device\Harddisk1\Partition0): Failed to open stream: No such file or directory
```

I am using PHP 8.2.10.

I also tried these paths but I get the same error:

```
\\?\Device\Harddisk1\Partition1
\\?\Device\Harddisk0\Partition0
\\?\Device\Harddisk0\Partition1
\\?\Device\Harddisk0
\\?\Device\Harddisk1
```

If this is not possible in PHP I'd welcome an explanation why exactly it's not supported.
I am writing my own data recovery script. It's already running well on Linux but I want to port it to Windows.

Comment: Linux exposes many internals (disks, devices, processes, etc.) as regular files, because that's how Unix was designed. But, as far as I know, Windows has never followed that path. I'm sure that `TYPE \\\\?\\Device\\Harddisk1\\Partition0` in a Windows Command Prompt doesn't work either.

Answer (score 1):

Congratulations on accidentally discovering a bug in PHP, it lies in [this line](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/master/Zend/zend_virtual_cwd.c#L1102):

```
#ifdef ZEND_WIN32
    if (memchr(resolved_path, '*', path_length) ||
        memchr(resolved_path, '?', path_length)) { // <<<<<<<<<<<<<
        SET_ERRNO_FROM_WIN32_CODE(ERROR_INVALID_NAME);
        return 1;
    }
#endif
```

Obviously if the path contains a `?`, php will consider this to be an invalid path.

This is quite reasonable, and I don't think it is worth fixing, because Windows creates aliases for each partition, e.g.

```
\\?\Device\HarddiskVolume1
\\.\Volume{xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx}
\\.\c:
```

You can use `fopen` to open the next two forms (**administrator privileges required**).

[image: Example]

Comment: Interesting. But, path syntax aside, can you `fopen()` directories or partitions?

Comment: `fopen` can't open directories, but devices are possible. Check this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/fileapi/nf-fileapi-createfilew

Comment: `\\.\c:` works. `\\.\Volume...` not.

Comment: @zomega It should works too, maybe you made a typo, no tail slash.

Comment: @shingo I am no Windows expert but perhaps it's `\\?\Volume...` and not `\\.\Volume...` as you can see on [this](https://icewolffile.blob.core.windows.net/$web/201505/ReFS_05.jpg) screenshot.

Comment: @zomega I am not too, but it just works. I added a screenshot to prove it. Also [this docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/fileio/naming-a-file#win32-device-namespaces) says ``\\.\`` is a valid prefix to access volumes.

Comment: @shingo I had a trailing slash after the volume path. Now it's working.

Answer (score 0):

Fundamentally this is a windows issue.

Windows doesn't work like this.